# OpenShift - URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 13] Permission denied>

Tags: python, wsdl, runtime-error, openshift, suds

I have a problem with SUDS , python2.7 and OpenShift . when I try to query the web service WSDL throws me the error:

```
URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 13] Permission denied>
```

This is the address of the WSDL that it generates the error.

```
suds.client import from Client
urlmps = ' http://www.mps.com.co:91/ArticuloDisponible.asmx?wsdl '
c = Client ( urlmps )
print c

URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 13] Permission denied>
```

When I try to query from webservicex.net if it works.

```
suds.client import from Client
url = ' http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx?WSDL '
client = Client ( url )
print client

Suds ( https://fedorahosted.org/suds/ ) version: 0.4 GA build: R699 - 20100913

Service ( GlobalWeather ) tns = " http://www.webserviceX.NET "
   Prefixes (0)
   Ports ( 2):
      ( GlobalWeatherSoap )×
         Methods ( 2):
            GetCitiesByCountry ( xs : string CountryName , )
            GetWeather ( xs : string CityName , xs : string CountryName , )
         Types ( 0):
      ( GlobalWeatherSoap12 )
         Methods ( 2):
            GetCitiesByCountry ( xs : string CountryName , )
            GetWeather ( xs : string CityName , xs : string CountryName , )
         Types ( 0):
```

The full track error in the pastebin..

http://pastebin.com/UgxtwPWP

Note: Running virtual environment from my local computer works perfectly, what I find is that the port 91 is denied from OpenShift.

Thanks, 
Mario Pardo

Comment: Clearly you are not allowed accessing the service.

Comment: The URLs in your python and .net code aren't the same--one has caps and the other lowercase. Plus, the spaces are the URL in both cases are invalid; it's easily possible that one environment magically fixed that for you and the other doesn't.

Comment: Upper or lower case letters do not have any change in the application, what I find is that this banned port visits for 91

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just incase anyone else stumbles upon this. Currently the only available external ports are `8080 8443 80 443`

It is possible to bind to the internal IP with port range: 15000 - 35530. All other ports are reserved for specific processes to avoid conflicts. Since we're binding to the internal IP, you will need to use port forwarding to access it: https://openshift.redhat.com/community/blogs/getting-started-with-port-forwarding-on-openshift